# Автоматическая пагинация на Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Проблема такая: отображаются дублирующие опубликованные посты при автоматической пагинации, что, естественно, некорректно.
Можно со страницы home удалить блочный контейнер и тогда пагинация будет появляется с шаблона home_list, но в таком случае пропадает возможность удалять свои же опубликованные посты.
Постраничная пагинация для меня это прошлый век, поэтому пытаюсь реализовать автоматическую пагинацию, работает, но дублируются посты.
Что я не досмотрел или где допустил ошибку?

views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.db.models import Q



def load_posts(request):
    # Получаем номер страницы из запроса
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)  # Устанавливаем значение по умолчанию на 1
    
    # Получаем ID пользователей, на которых подписан текущий пользователь
    subscribed_user_ids = Subscription.objects.filter(subscriber=request.user).values_list('target_user', flat=True)
    
    # Получаем все посты, на которых подписан текущий пользователь или которые он написал
    all_posts = Userpublication.objects.filter(Q(author__in=subscribed_user_ids) | Q(author=request.user))
    
    # Создаем объект Paginator
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 5)  # 5 постов на страницу
    
    try:
        # Получаем объекты для текущей страницы
        current_page_posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # Если номер страницы не является целым числом, показываем первую страницу
        current_page_posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # Если номер страницы находится за пределами допустимого диапазона, возвращаем пустой ответ
        return JsonResponse({'posts_html': '', 'next_page_url': None})
    
    # Рендерим HTML с постами текущей страницы
    posts_html = render_to_string('****/home_list.html', {'posts': current_page_posts})

    # Получаем URL для следующей страницы, если она существует
    next_page_url = None
    if current_page_posts.has_next():
        next_page_url = f"{reverse('load_posts')}?page={current_page_posts.next_page_number()}"
    
    # Возвращаем JSON-ответ с HTML и URL следующей страницы
    return JsonResponse({'posts_html': posts_html, 'next_page_url': next_page_url})
```

urls:

```
path('load-posts/', views.load_posts, name='load_posts'),
```

home.html:

```
<div id="post_contenter">
{% for post in post_lists|slice:":5" %}

<div class="post_content" id="post_content"> <!-- Добавляем идентификатор post_content -->
    <div class="post_header">
        <div class="post_user_avatar">
            {% if post.author.avatar %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{{ post.author.avatar.url }}" class="user-picture-small">
            {% else %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{% static '****/img/avatar.png' %}" class="card_user_picture_small">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="post_user_info">
            <div class="post_user_fullname"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' post.author.username %}" class="post_user_fullname_style">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</a></div>
            <div class="post_user_username"><a href="{{ user_profile.username }}" class="post_user_nickname_style">@{{ post.author }}</a>


                 {% if post.author.verification %}
    <span class="verified_user_small"></span>
                {% endif %}
                
            </div>
            <div class="post_user_date"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="post_user_date_style">{{ post.time_create }} {{ post.time_create|naturaltime }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_more">
        <div class="dropdown dropbtn" style="float:right;">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                {% if request.user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'edit_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_edit">Редактировать</a></span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'delete_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_delete">Удалить запись</a></span>
                {% endif %}
                
                <span><a href="" class="post_user_complain">Пожаловаться</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_content">
        {{ post.content }}
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_action">
        



<div class="post_user_liked_post">
    

{% if liked_by_current_user %}
    <div class="unlike-button" id="unlike-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% else %}
    <div class="like-button" id="like-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% endif %}
    <div class="count_likevalue">
        <span class="like-count-value like_count_style" id="like-count-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">{{ like_count }}</span>
    </div>


</div>

        <div class="containercomment_post">
            <!-- Уникальный идентификатор для каждого поста -->
    <div class="post_user_comment_post" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <span class="count_comment">{{ post.comments.count }}</span>
    </div>

        </div>
        <div class="post_user_share_post"></div>  
        <div class="post_user_views_post">
            <div class="post_user_views_post_count"><span class="post_user_views_post_count_style">125025</span></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    


            <!-- Уникальный идентификатор для каждой формы комментария -->
    <div class="comment-form hidden" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <hr>
        <form action="{% url 'add_comment' post_id=post.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea name="content" class="user_comment_style" placeholder="Написать комментарий..." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="img_sbmt"></button>
        </form>
    </div>

<!-- Отображение всех комментариев -->
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment_post">
            {% if comment.author.avatar %}
                <img src="{{ comment.author.avatar.url }}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% else %}
                <img src="{% static '****/img/avatar.png' %}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="comment_author"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' username=comment.author.username %}">{{ comment.author.first_name }}</a></div> 
            <div class="comment_content" id="comment-content-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.content }}</div>
            <div class="comment_time">{{ comment.created_at }}
                <!--<span class="answer_comment_user"><a>Ответить</a></span>-->
{% if comment.author == request.user %}
    <span id="edit-actions-{{ comment.id }}" class="edit_comment_user">
        <a href="#" onclick="editComment({{ comment.id }})" class="edit_comment_link">редактировать</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="saveComment(event, {{ comment.id }})" class="save_comment_link" style="display: none;">Сохранить изменения</a>
    </span>
    <span class="delete_comment_user"><a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment_id=comment.id %}">удалить</a></span>
{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <!-- Если текущий комментарий не последний, добавляем разделитель -->
            <hr class="solid_bottom">
        {% endif %}
        <span class="massage_save_comment_error"></span> <!-- Сообщение об ошибке -->
        <span id="save-message-{{ comment.id }}" class="massage_save_comment"></span> <!-- Сообщение о сохранении -->
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    <br>
</div>

{% endfor %}


</div>




    <!-- Пагинация -->

<div id="loading" class="pagination_pages" data-page="2"></div>


</div>






<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nextPageUrl = '/load-posts/';  // Используем URL для загрузки постов
    
    function loadMorePosts() {
        // Показываем элемент загрузки
        //$('#loading').text('Загрузка...');

        // Выполняем GET запрос к серверу
        $.get(nextPageUrl, function(data) {
            // Скрываем элемент загрузки
            //$('#loading').text('Загрузить еще');

            // Добавляем HTML с постами в конец контейнера
            $('#post_contenter').append(data.posts_html);

            // Обновляем URL следующей страницы
            nextPageUrl = data.next_page_url;
        }).fail(function() {
            // Обрабатываем ошибку запроса, если она произошла
            console.error('Ошибка при загрузке постов');
            // Скрываем элемент загрузки
            $('#loading').hide();
        });
    }

    // Обработчик события прокрутки страницы
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            // Вызываем функцию загрузки дополнительных постов
            loadMorePosts();
        }
    });

    // Инициализация загрузки первой страницы постов при загрузке страницы
    loadMorePosts();
});
</script>
```

home_list.html:

```
<!-- ****/home_list.html -->

{% load humanize %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if posts %}
    <div class="post-list">
        {% for post in posts %}
           <div class="post_content" id="post_content"> <!-- Добавляем идентификатор post_content -->
    <div class="post_header">
        <div class="post_user_avatar">
            {% if post.author.avatar %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{{ post.author.avatar.url }}" class="user-picture-small">
            {% else %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{% static '****/img/avatar.png' %}" class="card_user_picture_small">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="post_user_info">
            <div class="post_user_fullname"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' post.author.username %}" class="post_user_fullname_style">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</a></div>
            <div class="post_user_username"><a href="{{ user_profile.username }}" class="post_user_nickname_style">@{{ post.author }}</a>


                 {% if post.author.verification %}
    <span class="verified_user_small"></span>
                {% endif %}
                
            </div>
            <div class="post_user_date"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="post_user_date_style">{{ post.time_create }} {{ post.time_create|naturaltime }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_more">
        <div class="dropdown dropbtn" style="float:right;">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                {% if request.user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'edit_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_edit">Редактировать</a></span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'delete_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_delete">Удалить запись</a></span>
                {% endif %}
                
                <span><a href="" class="post_user_complain">Пожаловаться</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_content">
        {{ post.content }}
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_action">
        



<div class="post_user_liked_post">
    

{% if liked_by_current_user %}
    <div class="unlike-button" id="unlike-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% else %}
    <div class="like-button" id="like-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% endif %}
    <div class="count_likevalue">
        <span class="like-count-value like_count_style" id="like-count-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">{{ like_count }}</span>
    </div>


</div>

        <div class="containercomment_post">
            <!-- Уникальный идентификатор для каждого поста -->
    <div class="post_user_comment_post" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <span class="count_comment">{{ post.comments.count }}</span>
    </div>

        </div>
        <div class="post_user_share_post"></div>  
        <div class="post_user_views_post">
            <div class="post_user_views_post_count"><span class="post_user_views_post_count_style">125025</span></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    


            <!-- Уникальный идентификатор для каждой формы комментария -->
    <div class="comment-form hidden" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <hr>
        <form action="{% url 'add_comment' post_id=post.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea name="content" class="user_comment_style" placeholder="Написать комментарий..." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="img_sbmt"></button>
        </form>
    </div>

<!-- Отображение всех комментариев -->
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment_post">
            {% if comment.author.avatar %}
                <img src="{{ comment.author.avatar.url }}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% else %}
                <img src="{% static '****/img/avatar.png' %}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="comment_author"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' username=comment.author.username %}">{{ comment.author.first_name }}</a></div> 
            <div class="comment_content" id="comment-content-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.content }}</div>
            <div class="comment_time">{{ comment.created_at }}
                <!--<span class="answer_comment_user"><a>Ответить</a></span>-->
{% if comment.author == request.user %}
    <span id="edit-actions-{{ comment.id }}" class="edit_comment_user">
        <a href="#" onclick="editComment({{ comment.id }})" class="edit_comment_link">редактировать</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="saveComment(event, {{ comment.id }})" class="save_comment_link" style="display: none;">Сохранить изменения</a>
    </span>
    <span class="delete_comment_user"><a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment_id=comment.id %}">удалить</a></span>
{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <!-- Если текущий комментарий не последний, добавляем разделитель -->
            <hr class="solid_bottom">
        {% endif %}
        <span class="massage_save_comment_error"></span> <!-- Сообщение об ошибке -->
        <span id="save-message-{{ comment.id }}" class="massage_save_comment"></span> <!-- Сообщение о сохранении -->
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    <br>
</div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>Пока нет постов для отображения.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```